# How can I hide/show div or Toggle only with css?

Tags: html, css

I tried all questions & answers related this topic. Additionally and I tried related questions and try to solve it but not success. So please read my question deathly.

**Firstly have a look at the code what I made:**

```css
.clicker {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  color:#FFF;
}
.clicker.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.hiddendiv {
  height: 0px;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.5s;
}
.hiddendiv.nr2 {
  background-color: red;
}

#showdiv1:target ~ div a[href="#showdiv1"],
#showdiv2:target ~ div a[href="#showdiv2"] {
  display: none;
}
#showdiv1:target ~ div a[href="#hidediv1"],
#showdiv2:target ~ div a[href="#hidediv2"] {
  display: inline-block;
}
#showdiv1:target ~ div .hiddendiv.nr1,
#showdiv2:target ~ div .hiddendiv.nr2 {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="showdiv1"></div>
<div id="showdiv2"></div>

<div>
  <a href="#showdiv1" class="clicker" tabindex="1">Click me 1</a>
  <a href="#hidediv1" class="clicker hidden" tabindex="1">Click me 1</a>

  <a href="#showdiv2" class="clicker" tabindex="2">Click me 2</a>
  <a href="#hidediv2" class="clicker hidden" tabindex="2">Click me 2</a>

  <div class="hiddendiv nr1"></div>
  <div class="hiddendiv nr2"></div>
</div>
```

**I want to:**

1. Replace all the anchor tag with div only. **example**:

> < a href="#showdiv1" class="clicker" tabindex="1">Click me 1

**to:**

> < div id="#showdiv1" class="clicker" tabindex="1">Click me 1

**Reason: why I trying to do this?**

I am making a popup like an image given below and for that, I need a way that if I click on **SOCIAL** then **social div** appears(hide the manual div) and If I click on **MANUAL** then **manual div** appears. (hide the social div)

[image]

And when I try to paste the toggle code inside my popup code this is what happens:

[image]

see! the popup disappears when I click. that's why I need to remove the anchor tag with div or find any other way to do it.

**Popup code:**

```css
.modalDialog {
position: fixed;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
z-index: 99999;
opacity:0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
opacity:1;
pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > #__spookyPopup {
width: 400px;
position: relative;
margin: 10% auto;
padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
border-radius: 10px;
background: #fff;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #fff);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}



.profile_container
{    
height:160px;
width:400px;   
background:#ccc; 
display:inline-block;    
}
.profile_div
{
height:120px;
width:130px; 
margin-top:20px;
margin-left:130px;    
background:#ddd; 
border:1px solid grey;
}
.head_div
{
min-height:12px;
width:100%;              
}
    
.media_layer
{
margin-top:20px;
mi-height:12px;
width:400px;   
background:#; 
display:inline-block;    
}
    
    
.manual
{
height:50px;
width:197px;
float:right;    
background:#;
display:inline-block;       
}
.manual:hover
{
border-bottom:2px solid #ab0a72; 
}
.social
{ 
height:50px;
width:197px;       
background:#;    
display:inline-block;
    
}
.social:hover
{
border-bottom:2px solid #ab0a72; 
}
    
  
    
  




.clicker {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  color:#FFF;
}
.clicker.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.hiddendiv {
  height: 0px;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.5s;
}
.hiddendiv.nr2 {
  background-color: red;
}

#showdiv1:target ~ div a[href="#showdiv1"],
#showdiv2:target ~ div a[href="#showdiv2"] {
  display: none;
}
#showdiv1:target ~ div a[href="#hidediv1"],
#showdiv2:target ~ div a[href="#hidediv2"] {
  display: inline-block;
}
#showdiv1:target ~ div .hiddendiv.nr1,
#showdiv2:target ~ div .hiddendiv.nr2 {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#__spooky_auth_popup">Open Modal</a>

<div id="__spooky_auth_popup" class="modalDialog">
<div id="__spookyPopup">
<a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
 <div class="profile_container">
    
  <div class="profile_div"></div>
   </div>
<div class="head_div">
  <p style="margin:0;padding:0;text-align:center;
          font-size:25px;color:#8d8686;"><I>Hey, please login to access your private content.</I></p>
</div>
     
<div class="media_layer">
     
  <div class="social" >
   <p style="margin:0;padding:0;text-align:center;
          font-size:25px;color:#000;line-height:50px;">SOCIAL</p>
  </div>
        
<div class="manual">
  <p style="margin:0;padding:0;text-align:center;
          font-size:25px;color:#000;line-height:50px;">MANUAL</p>
 </div>
       
       
</div>
   
 <div id="showdiv1"></div>
<div id="showdiv2"></div>

<div>
  <a href="#showdiv1" class="clicker" tabindex="1">Click me 1</a>
  <a href="#hidediv1" class="clicker hidden" tabindex="1">Click me 1</a>

  <a href="#showdiv2" class="clicker" tabindex="2">Click me 2</a>
  <a href="#hidediv2" class="clicker hidden" tabindex="2">Click me 2</a>

  <div class="hiddendiv nr1"></div>
  <div class="hiddendiv nr2"></div>
```

If anyone have an idea how to do it it would be great.
Thanks in Advance.

**Note:** *Only pure CSS,CSS3 Use in Answer not use (javascript,jquery) & any other from control*

Comment: Question isn't very clear to me. Sounds like you want to show and hide a div by clicking a button? Are these `a` tags static? I don't see the point in changing an `a` to a `div`

Comment: just see this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/io74S.png   this is what I am trying todo sir.

Comment: A simple left right toogle only with css

Comment: You can not just replace those links with divs - that they _are_ links is part of what makes this work in the first place. Your problem seems to be, that you are opening your modal using the same technique - and this is what makes it simply unsuitable for what you want to achieve to begin with, because this technique allows you to manage only one “state”, whereas you need to manage two here (state 1: is the modal opened or not, and state 2: social or manual.)

Comment: I am not opening the modal here my question is how can I achieve toggle only with css. your not understand my question properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the hover state so you keep the popup open when you click inside:

```css
.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target,.modalDialog:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog>#__spookyPopup {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #fff);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

.profile_container {
  height: 160px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
}

.profile_div {
  height: 120px;
  width: 130px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 130px;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.head_div {
  min-height: 12px;
  width: 100%;
}

.media_layer {
  margin-top: 20px;
  min-height: 12px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #;
  display: inline-block;
}

.manual {
  height: 50px;
  width: 197px;
  float: right;
  background: #;
  display: inline-block;
}

.manual:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ab0a72;
}

.social {
  height: 50px;
  width: 197px;
  background: #;
  display: inline-block;
}

.social:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ab0a72;
}

.social_link_container {
  height: 160px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
}

.fb_container {
  height: 50px;
  width: 340px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.clicker {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #FFF;
}

.clicker.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.hiddendiv {
  height: 0px;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.5s;
}

.hiddendiv.nr2 {
  background-color: red;
}

#showdiv1:target~div a[href="#showdiv1"],
#showdiv2:target~div a[href="#showdiv2"] {
  display: none;
}

#showdiv1:target~div a[href="#hidediv1"],
#showdiv2:target~div a[href="#hidediv2"] {
  display: inline-block;
}

.hiddendiv.nr1 {
 height:150px;
}

#showdiv1:target~div .hiddendiv.nr1,
#showdiv2:target~div .hiddendiv.nr2 {
  height: 150px;
}
#showdiv2:target~div .hiddendiv.nr1 {
  height:0px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#__spooky_auth_popup">Open Modal</a>

<div id="__spooky_auth_popup" class="modalDialog">
  <div id="__spookyPopup">
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>



    <div class="profile_container">

      <div class="profile_div"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="head_div">
      <p style="margin:0;padding:0;text-align:center;
          font-size:25px;color:#8d8686;">
        <I>Hey, please login to access your private content.</I>
      </p>
    </div>


    <div class="media_layer">

      <div class="social">
        <p style="margin:0;padding:0;text-align:center;
          font-size:25px;color:#000;line-height:50px;">SOCIAL</p>
      </div>


      <div class="manual">
        <p style="margin:0;padding:0;text-align:center;
          font-size:25px;color:#000;line-height:50px;">MANUAL</p>
      </div>


    </div>

    <div id="showdiv1"></div>
    <div id="showdiv2"></div>

    <div>
      <a href="#showdiv1" class="clicker" tabindex="1">Click me 1</a>
      <a href="#hidediv1" class="clicker hidden" tabindex="1">Click me 1</a>

      <a href="#showdiv2" class="clicker" tabindex="2">Click me 2</a>
      <a href="#hidediv2" class="clicker hidden" tabindex="2">Click me 2</a>

      <div class="hiddendiv nr1"></div>
      <div class="hiddendiv nr2"></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: thankyou very much Temani sir. its work can you load the popup on page load instead of clicking the link. without js? and #showdiv1 by default?

Comment: @navjotsingh yes, when, simply append the anchor to your link `#__spookyPopup` ... so you have `http://link.com#__spookyPopup` and the popup will open on page load ;)

Comment: oh yes! and what about #showdiv1 by default? right now its currently show no div by default I want green div show by default when I open the popup

Comment: @navjotsingh let me think about this ;)

Comment: sure sir your are expert :D